# Removing class after adding it in Switch Case

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I remove the jumping class without having to call another function to remove it?
I would like the function to change the styling and then remove the class because the key up event interupts others styling changes in the code. Is Set Interval appropriate to use here?

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', jump);
document.addEventListener('keyup', landing);

function jump(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      if (!spritejump.classList.contains('jumping'))
        spritejump.classList.add('jumping');
      break;
  }
}

function landing(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      if (spritejump.classList.contains('jumping'))
        spritejump.classList.remove('jumping');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [mre] of what you are trying to achieve by pressing <> button in editor and making a fiddle. Ill take I wield guess here jumping is CSS animation, and You want it to stop, so show us CSS etc..

Comment: Instead of checking if it's there or not, simply use `spritejump.classList.toggle('jumping')`. Also, you shouldn't work with `keyCode`. Instead, use `event.key`.

Comment: Apologies, quiet new here. I am wondering if setInterval can be used inside my jump function to remove the class added in that function. Otherwise having to require a different function/event listener to handle removing the jumping class interferes with other functions controlling movement around the screen. I can't jump and move at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how long your (e.g.) animation is, you could use setTimeout.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
      // add the jumping class
      spritejump.classList.add('jumping');

      // remove the jumping class after 2 seconds
      setTimeout(() => {
        spritejump.classList.remove('jumping');
      }, 2000);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` only guarantees that code will not be executed *before* the amount of time specified.